# Jasper Web Service don't shows mandatory input control

Tags: web, input, controls, jasperserver

I have two input control "Select Single Query" that I have set as "Mandatory". The second parameter depends on the first. When I run the report in Jasper Server the parameters work well, but when I run it in the Jasper Server Web Service the second parameter remains blank!! How is it possible?

Thank you so much!